# I'm confused as to why my query isn't returning the correct items

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I added this item to my db

```
   title: green shorts
   upc: 999
   description: mens polyester blend
   brand: lrg
   location: row-1
```

This is my query

```
client.query('SELECT DISTINCT id, title FROM items WHERE fk = $1 AND ( title ILIKE $2 OR description ILIKE $2 OR custom1 ILIKE $2 OR custom2 ILIKE $2 OR sku ILIKE $2) OR (upc = $2) ',  [data.fk, data.search],  (err, res) => {
```

if data.search is blank or '' then the green shorts are returned,
but if data.search = 'green' it's not returning anything?
Is something wrong with my query?

I want to be able to search the term "green" and search for any items with the word green in title, description, brand, upc or location

Is ILIKE not the right term?

Comment: You need wild cards: '%green%'.

Comment: oh okay, so since I pass in data.search should it be like '%' data.search '%' ???

Comment: You could just try %data.search% - should work if the variable is properly declared.

Comment: got it! thanks I ended up going with '%'+ data

Comment: 'a%' gets anything that starts with 'a', and '%a' gets anything that ends with 'a', '%a%' gets anything that contains an 'a' anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the % symbol to denote wildcards.

```
WHERE title LIKE '%searchTerm%'
```

will return anything that contains the search term.

Comment: how do you pass a variable in with %?  if i use [data.fk,'%' data.search '%'] it errors

Comment: for a variable you need '+' symbol to combine '%'+ variable +'%'

Answer (score 1):

`=` gives the exact match but `Like` is used to get the results that match a pattern i.e. that include wild cards.

You need to use `%` to denote a pattern 
for instance as in your case you need green to match wherever found that would take two `%'s` to get green inscribed i.e.
`select ..... where title like "%green%"`